# Can't add a Page with Name 2011

Tags: permalinks

I've no idea why i can't add a Page with Name `2011`. Wordpress changes the URL Slug to 2011-01.

There is no Post with this Name in my Database. I tried zu flush my rewrite rules but nothing seems to be work.

If i add a Page 2013 it works fine. But only once... If i delete this Page (from Trash) i can't add it again. Wordpress changes the slug to 2013-01. If i change the Post name directly in the database. Nothing happens...

I really wonder why because there is no Post with this Name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because if you go to example.com/2011 you should be taken to an archive page of all post from 2011. 2013 works because you don't have any post dated 2013 (id assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how paging-within-a-page works. See ticket [#5305](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305). There's a plugin that will allow you to have numeric slugs if you're willing to sacrifice paging: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-numeric-stubs/